# Appending Characters in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my Android application I want to add charecters while the user is entering the data. (ex:if user enters 'a' I want to show '(a' in EditText).

Comment: Isn't that what it's supposed to do? :-\

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens automatically. When the EditText gains focus, a connection is made between the edittext and the input manager. Basically anything that is entered via the input manager is then sent to the edittext. So just by clicking on the EditText on the screen and then typing, the letters should appear on their own.